# Is it possible to create a Dropbox App to copy files from one file to another using PHP?

Tags: php, dropbox

I managed to create an Dropbox app to upload photos to my Dropbox account. I was wondering whether it is possible to execute a php from my website to copy file from one folder to another in the same account?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#fileops-copy

Comment: The dropbox API is a good place look

Answer (score 0):

Send a POST request to `https://api.dropbox.com/1/fileops/copy` with `root`, `from_path` and `to_path` parameters.

Full documentation at [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#fileops-copy)